# How to add constraints programmatically to two UI items (label and button?

Tags: swift

Ideally, I want the label and button to look like this:[image]

How would I set the constraints programmatically? Currently the code I have is:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let frame: CGRect = tableView.frame

        let label: UILabel = {
            let lb = UILabel()
            lb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            lb.text = "@\(userM) \(postM)"
            lb.font = lb.font.withSize(14)
            lb.textColor = .black
            lb.backgroundColor = .white
            lb.numberOfLines = 0
            return lb
        }()

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 25))
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        button.setTitle("Answer", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)


        let header: UIView = {
            let hd = UIView()
            hd.addSubview(label)
            hd.addSubview(button)
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hd.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hd.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hd.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hd.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

            return hd
        }()

        return header

    }
```

However, the code returns the button too far down the screen, and it isn't formatted correctly.  What additional constraints would I need to set on the button to have it on the bottom of the dynamic TextView and in line with the left side of the UILabel?
[image]

Comment: Inside the bracket where you set the constraints for the label, you're not setting any for the button. Add your button constraints as you did the label. I would just set the Button's leading anchor to 10, and it's topAnchor equal to the label's bottomAnchor with a constant of 10.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/59594708/2229783?

Answer (score 0):

You did not set constraints for `button`. Add the following lines to the block where you set constraints for `label`:

```
button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hd.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hd.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
```

Remove `label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hd.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true`, you don't need this constraint.

Don't forget to implement `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat` and `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat`, it is necessary to determine the header height:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SnapKit you can set constraint programmatically with the following code as example :

```
import SnapKit

    hd.addSubview(label)
    hd.addSubview(button)

    label.snp.makeConstraints { (cons) in
        cons.top.equalToSuperview()
        cons.left.equalToSuperview()
    }

    button.snp.makeConstraints { (cons) in
        cons.top.equalTo(button.snp_bottom)
        cons.left.equalToSuperview()
    }
```